# Possible options to hard-code a Tableau dashboard with two columns containing same text

Tags: tableau-api, hardcoded

I have a tableau dashboard which pulls tasks for daily auditing. This auditing is done on a tool and the upload file has to be an excel sheet. This excel sheet however has three columns that are specific to the tool and doesn't have any related data on the data source that feeds my tableau dashboard. 
At present, I do a crosstab download of my tableau dashboard and then manually add those three columns and then upload to my auditing tool.

Is there a way to automate this part?

I am looking for something similar in SQL where we use

SQL code
select
'' as Auditor name,
'ABC' as Node,
'US' as Program
from
tablename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only want 3 dummy fields which will export.I'll assume you want Auditor Name to be empty, Node to contain ABC and Program to be US. Create these calculated fields and drop them into your export view:

```
[Auditor Name]: ""

[Node]: "ABC"

[Program]: "US"
```

Obviously it's simple to alter the contents of these fields to anything you want.